# Meaning of the term"Pitches the bouncing ponies"

Tags: meaning-in-context

From Virginia Woolf's *Mrs Dalloway*, [Chapter 1](https://www.readinggroupguides.com/reviews/mrs-dalloway/excerpt):

> [...] wrapped in the soft mesh of the grey-blue morning air, which, as the day wore on, would unwind them, and set down on their lawns and pitches the bouncing ponies whose forefeet just struck the ground and up they sprung, the whirling young men, and laughing girls in their transparent muslins who, even now, after dancing all night, were taking their absurd woolly dogs for a run [...]

What does the term " pitches the bouncing ponies" mean?

Comment: I am CV'ing this question because it's based on a misreading of the text. The coordinated phrase is "lawns and pitches". "The bouncing ponies" is the direct object of "set down".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - but that's rather difficult to see here. I suggest you make that an answer, and maybe we can migrate it to ELL.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan But what does "to pitch" ponies mean? is it a game?

Comment: As Marc says, it's a misreading. The ponies were set down on the lawns and pitches.

Comment: @Heartspring I think that this question would better be closed, because I doubt that it will be helpful to many people in the future. (Will they have been confused in the same way by this exact same passage? Or by a similar passage elsewhere? Perhaps, but I think that's unlikely.) However, I see that my close-vote has somehow been cancelled (have TPTB struck ELU again?), so OK. :)

Comment: After looking at the history I see that the question was actually closed and reopened. OK, then, an answer it is.

Comment: The verbs are governed by  **would**  and must be non-finite:  *would ... unwind .... (would)  set down on their lawns*.  **pitches** cannot be a verb in that sentence.

Comment: This section of the passage is a bit difficult to parse at first. sight because it uses a non-canonical phrase order. The idiom *set down* allows for a Direct Object of the verb *set*, which tells you what is being placed,  and also a locative complement, which tells you where it is put. The direct object will normally occur either between *set* and *down* (which it must do if a personal pronoun), or after *down*:. So either: *She set **the pen** down **on the table*** or *She set down [**the pen** [**on the table**].* Here however, the DO has been shunted to the end of the clause ... (cont)

Comment: If we did this with our example we'd get: *She set down [**on the table**] [**the pen**]. This marked word order is more becoming in Virginia Woolf's example because the direct object is very, very long: *the bouncing ponies whose forefeet just struck the ground.* We often shunt long phrases or even long parts of phrases down to the end of a clause where they are easier  for a listener to process. The normal phrase order would be: *... set down [**the bouncing ponies whose forefeet just struck the ground**] [**on the lawns and pitches**]* - where the word *pitches* refers to cricket pitches.

Comment: In case it doesn't get reopened, the phrase "... [they] set down on their lawns and pitches the bouncing ponies whose forefeet just struck the ground..." -> "They set down the ponies (small horses)" Where? "... on their lawns and pitches..." What kind of ponies? "... [the ones] whose forefeet just struck the ground".

Answer (score 4):

This question seems to be based on a misreading of the text. For one thing, there is nothing singular that could reasonably serve as the subject of the "pitches" if that word were a verb (in which case it would have to be in third-person singular form).

Intsead, the coordinated phrase "their lawns and pitches" serves as the object of "on", and "the bouncing ponies" serves as the direct object of "set down":

> . . . and [set down [on their lawns and pitches] [the bouncing ponies [whose forefeet just struck the ground]]] . . .

Comment: So it's the plural from of pitch, like a football (soccer) pitch? Why are the lawns and pitches together? Is this some sort of racing course?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it seems to be the plural form of "pitch" as in a field on which sports are played (though perhaps the meaning was somewhat different a century ago). I can't say why Woolf chose to write "lawns and pitches" as opposed to using some other words.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I wrote "the verb 'pitches'" in my first paragraph (if that's what you're referring to) to point out that that interpretation wasn't possible in this sentence. I could try to re-word that if it seems confusing.

Comment: I did a bit of reading, it's the men playing cricket: “a stirring of galloping ponies, *tapping of cricket bats*;” it's a cricket pitch.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks for the suggestion; I've tried to clarify that sentence a bit. Please feel free to edit if it can be made clearer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why would there be ponies on a cricket pitch? I would expect it to be referring to a polo field. In British, "pitch" can refer to any sporting field, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I presume that the "tapping of cricket bats""---> men playing on a cricket pitch. The "whirling young men" refers–I think–to the arm movements when [bowling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_(cricket)) (throwing)  a cricket ball. You have to read the extract in the link. I don't think ponies are used for polo, not with adult men riding.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — A polo pony is a horse (not a pony).

Comment: @TinfoilHat thank you, I had absolutely no idea! Did you already know that?

Comment: @Mari-LouA — I did. We also call race horses *ponies* — *the ponies are running*, *betting on the ponies*. It might be a US thing?

Comment: Some playing fields for sports are called pitches and others are called lawns. However, pitch is BrE.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parse is: and set down on their lawns and pitches the bouncing ponies=the bouncing ponies were set down on their lawns and pitches.

A fuller excerpt from Mrs. Dalloway
And everywhere, though it was still so early, there was *a beating, a stirring of galloping ponies, tapping of cricket bats*; Lords, Ascot, Ranelagh and all the rest of it; wrapped in the soft mesh of the grey-blue morning air, which, as the day wore on, would unwind them, and set down on their lawns and pitches the bouncing ponies whose forefeet just struck the ground and up they sprung, the whirling young men, and laughing girls in their transparent muslins who, even now, after dancing all night, were taking their absurd woolly dogs for a run;

[Btw: Lords, Ascot, and Ranelagh are places where well-to-do Londoners have done their sporting—cricket, horse-racing, polo.]
[blog about Mrs. Dalloway](https://zeteojournal.com/2014/11/02/mrs-dalloway/)

pitches and lawns are both types of playing fields. A cricket pitch and a lawn or field of grass where polo is played.